# Nativescript app will not running locally

Tags: nativescript

I have a nativescript app I have inherited and am trying to get it running locally. Here is what I am seeing:

```
ruby-2.4.1 marklocklear:foobar_app marklocklear$ tns run ios
Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
Executing before-liveSync hook from /Users/marklocklear/nativescript/foobar_app/hooks/before-liveSync/nativescript-angular-sync.js
Executing before-watchPatterns hook from /Users/marklocklear/nativescript/foobar_app/hooks/before-watchPatterns/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Executing before-watch hook from /Users/marklocklear/nativescript/foobar_app/hooks/before-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 2.9.2

15:17:35 - Starting compilation in watch mode...

15:17:40 - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

At this point the command line sits there...if I open the preview or playground app I get nothing on my iPhone (which is connected to my mac) I get nothing.

If I try `tns run ios --emulator` this opens an emulator locally, but I don't see the app anywhere on the emulator.

I have a couple of sample apps that I am able to run locally, so I think the framework is installed correctly. Here is what the root of the app looks like:

```
ls -la
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  10 marklocklear  staff    320 Oct 25 12:44 .
drwxr-xr-x@  7 marklocklear  staff    224 Oct 26 14:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x@ 31 marklocklear  staff    992 Oct 25 10:09 app
drwxr-xr-x   8 marklocklear  staff    256 Oct 25 12:44 hooks
drwxr-xr-x  64 marklocklear  staff   2048 Oct 25 12:44 node_modules
-rw-r--r--@  1 marklocklear  staff  19593 Oct 25 10:09 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--@  1 marklocklear  staff   1381 Oct 25 10:09 package.json
drwxr-xr-x@  5 marklocklear  staff    160 Oct 25 10:09 platforms
-rw-r--r--@  1 marklocklear  staff    271 Oct 25 10:09 references.d.ts
-rw-r--r--@  1 marklocklear  staff    681 Oct 25 12:44 tsconfig.json
```

Any ideas on how to trouble shoot this?

Comment: Try a clean build - delete your platforms, node_modules, hooks. You may manually launch your iOS Simulator you prefer and then do `tns run ios` again.

Comment: This kind of issue happened to me when there are versions mismatch, usually between TypeScript and NativeScript, you should create a new app and move your existing code inside it if you messed up with the versions of npm package manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your platform, node_modules and build again. Try a real device too.

Comment: In addition to this, I also had to run `tns deploy ios` to actually install/deploy the app to the emulator before it showed up.

Comment: @Sow I am new to nativescript app so can you please let me know how to  run this app?

Comment: @Rajpurohit Please go through the documentation of NativeScritpt at https://docs.nativescript.org/. It's pretty easy to set up environment for NativeScript and running apps. If you don't understand anything feel free to ask.

Comment: @Sow Thanks for your reply, actually I have tried but could not understand so It will be good if we can talk more and can setup it properly let me know when we can do?